# Self answer adds orange backing to Answer not Question

Tags: bug, design, self-answer

After clicking self answer, it shows this:

[image]

I think it should not highlight anything, it should be the top of the page. It would make much more sense.

Comment: This is not a bug and got nothing to do with self answer. After you post a new answer, you are being redirected to that answer i.e. `http://[site]/questions/[question id]/[title]/[answer id]#[answer id]` - this is the expected behavior. Feel free to start feature request like "Do not redirect me to my newly posted answer" asking to just use AJAX or the live refresh.